# The type Lista is not generic; My list is correct?

Tags: java

Hi i having some trouble with: error

The type Lista is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments "Integer"

My files tests:

```
public class testy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista<Integer> l = new Lista<Integer>();
    l.add(5);
    l.add(7);
    //System.out.println(l.removeFirst());
}
}
```

List :

```
public class Lista implements Serializable{

ListaS<T> Lista;

public Lista() {
    Lista = new ListaS<T>(null, Lista, Lista);
    Lista.setNext(Lista);
    Lista.setPrevious(Lista);
}

 public int Rozmiar(){
     int counter = 0;
     if(nastepny == null)
          return counter;
      else{
          ListaS<T> tmp = counter;
          do{
              next = next.wezNastepny();
              counter++;
            }while(tmp != previous);
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public boolean Empty(){
        if(Size()== 0 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void addStart(T wartosc){
        ListaS<T> nowy = new ListaS<T>(wartosc);
        if(next == null){
            next=newnode;
            next=newnode;
            nowy.setNext(null);
            nowy.setPrevious(null);
        }else{
            nowy.setNext(nastepny);
            next.setPrevious(nowy);
            next = nowy;
        }       
    }

    public void addEnd(T wartosc){
        ListS<T> nowy = new ListaS<T>(value);
        if(previous == null){
            next=nowy;
            previous =nowy;
            newnode.setNext(null);
            newnode.setPrevious(null);
        }else{
            newnode.setPrevious(previous);
            previous.setNext(nowy);
            previous=nowy;
        }
    public E removeFirst() {
        if (size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        ListS tmp = next;
        next = next.getNext();
        next.setNext = null;
        System.out.println("deleted: "+tmp.value);
        return tmp.wezWartosc();
    }
}
```

And the last one

```
 public class ListaS<T> implements Serializable{
 T value;
 ListaS<T> next;
 ListaS<T> previous;

ListaS(T value, ListaS<T> next, ListaS<T> poprzedni) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
    this.previous = previous;
}

T getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setNext(ListaS<T> nastepny) {
    this.next = next;
}
public ListaS<T> getPrevious() {
    return previous;
}
public void setPrevious(ListaS<T> poprzedni) {
    this.previous = previous;
}
public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public ListaS<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}
}
```

Ok if we solve first problem could some one tell me my function are ok?
And how i should write removeLast()?

Comment: `Lista` doesn't have a generic type. What are you confused about?

Comment: Also, stick to one question please.

Comment: @shmosel could u explain me how can i repair that. Should i add Lista<T>?

Comment: Uh... make it generic? Just like `ListaS`.

Comment: @shmosel  I add Lista<T>, could u help me repair my other function?

Comment: What other function?

Comment: When i tried use anyone nothing work ;/

Comment: Sorry to hear...

Comment: @shmosel so could u help me pls i really need some help i m powerless.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want help with.

Comment: @shmosel i have to write function like Empty(), AddFirst(), AddLast(),RemoveFirst(),RemoveLast(). Pls help me man i really need to do this.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a free coding service. If you have a specific question, we might be able to help. So far I have yet to see any.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your `Lista` class definition in `public class Lista<T> implements Serializable`

Comment: I did yet. But now i have a problem with my function like Empty(), AddFirst(), AddLast(),RemoveFirst(),RemoveLast().

Comment: but this is another problem :) So try to understand what's wrong and in case you need help write on SO :))))

Comment: Could you just help me write 1 function which will write me all elemenets of my list? Please.